# How to set color of nth list item in listview android

Tags: android, listview

i searched a lot for this but i coudnt find any aswer or suitable links,

how to set a particular color for the nth list item in list view when list view is loaded.

say if i want to set the color of 10th list item to red when the list view is loaded..

Please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

simple  when list is loading

```
if(position == 10)
{
convertView.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
}
```

Comment: oh now i got it, we should do it in the adapter class itself right?

Comment: yeah when adapter is loading

Comment: actually what i needed was, when i click on alist item it will be redireted to another page and when i come back to the original listview page, it should load with last clicked position in different color, i did it with shared preference thank you for your aanswer